Wait then return non-promise from Vue3 method
This may just be a sanity check I'm needing, i.e. being told "you can't", or perhaps someone has a way.
I'm updating some originally rather quickly hacked legacy-ish code in Vue3 using the options API. There are a number of places where methods execute callback functions in other components, and those callbacks now need to contain async operations like HTTP requests to generate their return value. The calling functions expect a value, not a promise.
It would make my life easier if I could provide non-promise values rather than rewriting the calling functions, but insofar as I can tell this isn't possible.
Within the callback, using promises the traditional way:
callbackmethod() {
       let httpres=new Promise(function(resolve,reject) { 
                    output=...;
                    resolve(output);
            });
       httpres.then(
                function(data) { return data; },
                function(err) { console.log('got an error'); }
            );
}

my return of data is within the promise's resolve() function and I have no way of waiting for and returning data from the main body of the callback function to the caller.
The normal solution to this seems to be to use await (according to several hundred blogs and forum threads), but in Vue, I can only use await by declaring the funciton to be async, so it has to return a promise - doesn't help.

async callbackmethod() {
     let httpres=function(){
    data=...;
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){resolve(data);});
    };
     let res = await httpres;
     return res; //Gets wrapped in a promise anyway
}

So I think my only option is to rewrite the caller functions to expect promises, at which point I may as well do the following, but before I do so, I just wanted to check I'm not missing something.
callbackmethod() {
     let httpres=new Promise(function(resolve,reject) { 
                    output=...;
                    resolve(output);
            });
     return httpres;
}


This question is similar to: How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Having read that through, and noting my comments above about the particular aspects of implementation in VueJS, my conclusion as I feared is that there isn't a way, at least without close coupling of child and parent component logic (reducing reusability). I guess the lesson to take from this is to think very carefully when developing components and if there is any remote possibility that methods running callbacks they provide may ever have to do something asynchronous, design them to expect a promise in return.

Or, update those calling methods when it becomes an issue to test whether what they've been returned a value or a promise, and act accordingly.
